# How can I remove a window from NSScreen in order to get the Image without having that window?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am using this below function to get my CGImage Image and then I convert that image to needed type for my use case later:

```
func pixelColorReader(point: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> CGImage {
    
    let screenID = NSScreen.main!.deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as! UInt32
    let image: CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGDirectDisplayID(screenID), rect: CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: size.width, height: size.height))!
    return image
    
}
```

This function will work and it gave the needed image but think like that you have some apps open in desktop and you do not want that a window or an app be rendered in the image and you want NSScreen be able to omit just a special open app or window and not the other open apps. How can i do this? As I look to the function if this question have an answer it must come from NSScreen related topic.

More information think about you have a Finder window open in desktop and a Notepad and your MailBox app open in desktop, If we call that function in needed origin and size it would make an image what there exists, so what I want is: I want be able to tell NSScreen that ignore all MailBox open apps in desktop and just pretend that window does not exists and return the desktop image without showing that window in Image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CGWindow` API, specifically `CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray()`.

Here's how to generate a screenshot excluding the windows for Mail.app.

```
// preflight checks to see if we have permission. request performs the permission request.
BOOL hasScreenCaptureAccess = CGPreflightScreenCaptureAccess();
if (!hasScreenCaptureAccess) {
    // this is where you tell the user you need screen recording access in an alert or something. clearly explain why your app needs the permission and show the user what to do.
    hasScreenCaptureAccess = CGRequestScreenCaptureAccess();
    if (!hasScreenCaptureAccess) {
        NSLog(@"No screen capture access granted");
        return;
    }
}

// get the process ID from the bundle IDs whose windows you want to exclude. bundle IDs would be easier to use, but the CGWindow API returns process IDs.
NSSet<NSString *> *excludedAppBundleIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"com.apple.mail"]];
NSMutableSet<NSNumber *> *exclusionPIDs = [NSMutableSet new];
for (NSRunningApplication *app in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications) {
    if ([excludedAppBundleIDs containsObject:app.bundleIdentifier]) {
        [exclusionPIDs addObject:@(app.processIdentifier)];
    }
}

// loop through all window descriptions, getting the window IDs of every window we want in the screenshot. we ignore any window process ID that's in exclusionPIDs.
NSArray<NSDictionary *> *windowDescriptions = CFBridgingRelease(CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID));
NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *windowIDs = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *windowDict in windowDescriptions) {
    NSNumber *windowProcessID = windowDict[(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerPID];
    if (![exclusionPIDs containsObject:windowProcessID]) {
        NSNumber *windowID = windowDict[(NSString *)kCGWindowNumber];
        if (windowID) {
            [windowIDs addObject:windowID];
        }
    }
}

// CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray() expects a CFArrayRef of CGWindowIDs (value types) as pointers, not NSNumbers of CGWindowIDs (object types). we have to drop down to CFArray to create one of these things.
// cArray is pointer-sized (uintptr_t), not the size of our type (CGWindowID) because CFArrayCreate() demands pointer-sized values.
NSUInteger count = windowIDs.count;
uintptr_t cArray[count];
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    NSNumber *number = windowIDs[index];
    cArray[index] = (CGWindowID)(number.unsignedIntValue);
}
CFArrayRef cWindowIDArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)cArray, (CFIndex)count, NULL);

// finally, create the image
CGImageRef imageRef = CGWindowListCreateImageFromArray(CGRectInfinite, (CFArrayRef)cWindowIDArray, kCGWindowImageDefault);
if (!imageRef) {
    NSLog(@"No image available");
    return;
}

// release memory and create an imageRep
CFRelease(cWindowIDArray);
cWindowIDArray = nil;
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
CFRelease(imageRef);
imageRef = nil;

// do whatever with imageRep
```